# Why doesn't OCI-Lob->close work for IN OUT parameters?

Tags: php, oracle, clob, oci8, lob

From the documentation I've read regarding LOBs and the OCI8 PHP extension, it seems like I should call `$lob->close()` in the code below, since I have used `$lob->writeTemporary()`. `$lob->close()` works fine when I am passing a LOB to a stored procedure that accepts an IN parameter, but does not work if I am passing a LOB to a stored procedure that accepts an IN OUT parameter.

Obviously I can just leave out the call to `$lob->close()` for IN OUT parameters, but I am curious to know why I need to. Could someone please explain what is happening in the code below that causes it to produce the following error? Any insight is much appreciated.

*OCI-Lob::close() [oci-lob.close]: ORA-22289: cannot perform %s operation on an unopened file or LOB*

```
$my_clob = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...';

$connection = oci_connect('user', 'pass', 'connection string');
$statement  = oci_parse($connection, 'begin p_clob_in_out(:p_my_clob); end;');
$lob        = oci_new_descriptor($connection, OCI_D_LOB);

$lob->writeTemporary($my_clob, OCI_TEMP_CLOB);

oci_bind_by_name($statement, ':p_my_clob', $lob, -1, OCI_B_CLOB);

oci_execute($statement, OCI_DEFAULT);

if (is_object($lob))
{
  $data = $lob->load();

  $lob->close();
  $lob->free();
}

echo $data;
```

The `p_clob_in_out` procedure looks like this:

```
procedure p_clob_in_out(
    p_my_clob in out clob
)
is
begin
    p_my_clob := 'ABC123... ' || p_my_clob;
end p_clob_in_out;
```

---

Upon further reading thanks to [Vincent Malgrat's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119634/vincent-malgrat) answer, I think this is what is happening... In my PHP code, the `$lob` variable is a temporary LOB that is passed in. That temporary LOB is modified by the procedure, which creates a copy of it. The copy is then passed out and replaces the `$lob` variable. The `writeTemporary` method was never called on the copy of the LOB, so when I call `$lob->close()` it fails. The original LOB that was initially created (that I would be able to call `$lob->close()` on) is no longer accessible by the PHP script.

I think the NOCOPY hint may not apply here because on [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/tuning.htm#i48500) under "Restrictions on NOCOPY" it states that NOCOPY will be ignored if "the subprogram is called through a database link or as an external procedure". According to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg11rtn.htm#1000718), it sounds like the anonymous block in my PHP script that is calling the stored procedure would be considered an external procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run into a similar puzzling problem with temporary LOBs (pure Pl/SQL so may be similar in PHP). Some code that was working fine with persistent LOBS didn't work with temporary LOB. After some searching I found this note in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i1015757):

> A copy of a temporary LOB is created if the user modifies the temporary LOB while another locator is also pointing to it. The locator on which a modification was performed now points to a new copy of the temporary LOB. Other locators **no longer see the same data as the locator** through which the modification was made.

I would be curious to see if you run into the same problem if you specify [NOCOPY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/tuning.htm#sthref2256) in your procedure : `procedure p_clob_in_out(p_my_clob in out NOCOPY clob)`. Also can you check that your lob contains `'ABC123... '` after the procedure call?

My reasoning is the following: `IN` parameters are passed as reference, so the LOB is modified anyway when you pass it as an IN parameter. `IN OUT` parameters are passed by value so in effect you apply your procedure to a copy of the temporary LOB (persistent LOBs would not be deep-copied).

Comment: That sounds like it could have something to do with it, however, when I specify NOCOPY in the procedure I still run into the same problem. With or without NOCOPY, the LOB does contain the 'ABC123...' before I try to close it and the error occurs.

Comment: I think I may understand what's happening now thanks to the hints you provided in your answer. I edited my original question with my findings since they were too lengthy for this comment. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with your analysis. I'm wondering if the copy is an unexpected consequence of your assignment line (`p_my_clob := 'ABC123... ' || p_my_clob`). Could you test with the DBMS_LOB.writeappend function? i.e `dbms_lob.writeappend(p_my_clob, length('ABC123... '), 'ABC123... ')`

Comment: That actually worked! If I use the NOCOPY hint and `dbms_lob.writeappend` I am able to call `$lob->close()` successfully.